# Facebook posts in groups - background option not appearing

Tags: facebook

I can normally add background to my posts. However, I cannot do so in any group. I tried to do it with another account on the same computer and it works fine. Is there something wrong with the account I'm using?

Comment: The feature is probably not rolled out to that account.